# Powershell - Get date from week and weekday

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a file containing 'year', 'week-number', and 'weekday', (example - '2022', '42', '4',) 42 represents week 42 of 2022, and the 4 represents tuesday. A 7 would represent sunday.

The first week is to be considered the first days until sunday, regardless if it is 7 days or not. Same principle for the last week. That week can also contain fewer than 7 days.

How can i translate this to a date like 'yyyyMMdd'?

Thanks

Comment: Have you already managed to split the data into those 3 values?

Comment: Also, What would you like to do with the value?

Comment: Those value come in a csv file like this
....;year;week;weekday;
And i need to translate it to yyyyMMdd in order to get a proper datetime so my other system can understand it

Comment: @Rocket_Phantom Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70972146/edit) with the relevant details: When is a week to be considered the first week of a year? And does day 4 mean Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday?

Comment: Thats useful info. i added it. Thanks

Comment: So if _ 4 represents tuesday_, that would mean your week starts on a Saturday? What calendar is that? What would be the first weekday of the year for you? (for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) this would be Monday, January 3rd 2022)

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- The following uses .NET's [`System.DayOfWeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DayOfWeek) enumeration to identify weekdays, which means that Sunday is `0`, Monday is `1`, ..., and Saturday is `6`.
- If your weekday-numbering scheme differs (which is what it sounds like), you'll have to map it onto the above.

```sh
# Convert the strings (representing CSV input) to numbers.
[int] $year, [int] $week, [int] $weekday =  '2022', '42', '4'

# The day of the week you consider the start of a calendar week.
$startOfWeekDay = [DayOfWeek]::Monday

# Calculate the start of calendar week 1 for the given year:
# The Monday on or preceding Jan 1
# Note: This date may therefore fall into the previous year.
$Jan1 = [datetime]::new($year, 1, 1)
$StartOfWeek1 = $Jan1.AddDays(-((7 + $Jan1.DayOfWeek-$startOfWeekDay) % 7))

# Calculate the start of the target calendar week.
$StartOfTargetWeek = $StartOfWeek1.AddDays($week * 7)

# Calculate the target date by determining the desired weekday
# inside the target week.
$TargetDate = $StartOfTargetWeek.AddDays((7 + $weekday-$startOfWeekDay) % 7)
$TargetDateString = $TargetDate.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

# Output *for display* both the intermediate results and the final one.
[pscustomobject] @{
  Jan1 = ($Jan1 | Out-String).Trim()
  StartOfWeek1 = ($StartOfWeek1 | Out-String).Trim()
  StartOfTargetWeek = ($StartOfTargetWeek | Out-String).Trim()
  TargetWeekDay = [DayOfWeek] $weekday
  TargetDate = ($TargetDate | Out-String).Trim()
  TargetDateString = $TargetDateString
} | Format-List
```

Output:

```sh
Jan1              : Saturday, January 1, 2022 12:00:00 AM
StartOfWeek1      : Monday, December 27, 2021 12:00:00 AM
StartOfTargetWeek : Monday, October 17, 2022 12:00:00 AM
TargetWeekDay     : Thursday
TargetDate        : Thursday, October 20, 2022 12:00:00 AM
TargetDateString  : 20221020
```